# I need to restrict access to users from seeing/using Lightning custom Tab

Tags: apex, permissions, lightning-tab

I need to restrict access to users from seeing/using Lightning custom Tab. Not all users should get access to it. I want to control this with a permission set and I Need to remove tab access from all profiles so only this permission set grants access to the tab. This will ensure the correct users will see the Lightning tab.

Problem
I created a Permission set but I don't know where to manage lightning custom tab.
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can manage it. Just you need to follow these step.

1. From Setup, either: Enter Permission Sets in the Quick Find box, then select Permission Sets
2. Select a permission set.
3. Do one of the following:

Permission sets or enhanced profile user interface—In the Find Settings... box, enter the name of the tab you want and select it from the list, then click Edit.

Original profile user interface—Click Edit, then scroll to the Tab Settings section.

4. [Specify the tab settings.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=permissions_tab_settings_ref.htm&type=5) You need to specify the setting available there. Click on the hyperlink, you will get to know more about that.
5. Click Save.

> Note:- Tab settings specify whether a tab appears in the All Tabs page
>   or is visible in a tab set.

Reference:- [View and Edit Tab Settings in Permission Sets and Profiles](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_tab_visibility.htm&type=5)